# React w/Typescript: useReducer, Action Interface w/ Union Type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I'm attempting to create a reducer using the `useReducer` hook that uses an interface called Action that has a property that can either be a `string` or a `number`:

```
type Actions = 'update_foo' | 'update_bar';

interface Action {
    type: Actions;
    value?: number | string;
}
```

I also defined an interface for the initial state and a `const` for setting the default state:

```
interface InitialState {
    foo: number;
    bar: string;
}

const defaultState: InitialState = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 'bar'
}
```

And then my reducer function:

```
const fooBarReducer: React.Reducer<InitialState, Action> = (state: InitialState, action: Action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'update_foo':
            return { ...state, foo: action.value };
        case 'update_bar':
            return { ...state, bar: action.value };
        default:
            return defaultState;
    }
}
```

This issue that I'm running into is that Typescript doesn't seem to like the union type def and throws the following error:

```
Type '(state: InitialState, action: Action) => { foo: string | number | undefined; bar: string | number; }' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<InitialState, Action>'. 
Call signature return types '{ foo: string | number | undefined; bar: string | number; }' and 'InitialState' are incompatible. The types of 'foo' are incompatible between these types. 
Type 'string | number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number'. 
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.
```

I've used union types before but not with Reacts `useReducer` hook. This can be resolved by having a property separately for `foo` and `bar` in the `Action` interface, but I would like to use the union type if possible.

Any help would be most appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

The issue appears to be that you're using a type union at the field level. This means any field could be of any type (eg: `type` could be `update_foo` and `value` could be `"str"` which is invalid). If the `Action` `interface` is updated to be a union of actions (rather than each field being a union) this can achieve the type-safety you are looking for.

Now, when the `type` is `update_foo`, TypeScript will know that the `value` *must* be a `number`. And when `type` is `update_bar` TypeScript will know `value` *must* be a `string`.

I'm also assuming in the `update_bar` case, that should be `bar` instead of `foo`?

```js
type Action =
  | { type: "update_foo"; value: number }
  | { type: "update_bar"; value: string };

interface InitialState {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
}

const defaultState: InitialState = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: "bar"
};

const fooBarReducer: React.Reducer<InitialState, Action> = (
  state: InitialState,
  action: Action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "update_foo":
      return { ...state, foo: action.value };
    case "update_bar":
      return { ...state, bar: action.value };
    default:
      return defaultState;
  }
};
```

For more details, the pattern you're likely looking for is [discriminated unions](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions#discriminated-union).

Comment: Lol yeah the `update_bar` case should be bar instead of foo. I've updated the snippet. But thanks this works and I appreciate the thorough explanation!

Comment: don't forget to mark it as a solution ;)